# status=203/EXEC Error when creating code server

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu-18.04, code-server

I've created code server service on Ubuntu 18.04 nginx.
But gives error when run command :

> systemctl status code-server

Error :

```
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of code-server.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
● code-server.service - code-server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/code-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-09-02 17:45:29 CEST; 4min 53s ago
  Process: 4749 ExecStart=/usr/bin/code-server --bind-addr 127.0.0.1:8080 --user-data-dir /var/lib/code-server --auth password (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 4749 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

My /lib/systemd/system/code-server.service file as below

```
[Unit]
Description=code-server
After=nginx.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=PASSWORD=xxxxxx
ExecStart=/usr/bin/code-server --bind-addr 127.0.0.1:8080 --user-data-dir /var/lib/code-server --auth password
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I checked all topics, they say it's a missing path problem but I checked all paths and exists

```
root@xx:~# sudo mkdir /usr/lib/code-server
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/lib/code-server’: File exists
root@xx:~# sudo mkdir /var/lib/code-server
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/code-server’: File exists
root@xx:~#
```

I'm not a pro ubuntu user. What should I check ?